# Output unique content at the end of my php foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that outputs all the values for cells found in a Google Spreadsheet, wraps each value in a containing div and wraps a div around each row.

Everything is working properly until I get to the final iteration of the loop where I am left with an open div at the end of the iterations.

I know I need to add an elseIf statement that checks for the last iteration and outputs a closing div but I am lost as to how to accomplish this.

Here is my code:

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

$ic = 0; /* ITEM count: iterates item count up for every cell pulled from the spreadsheet */

$rc = 1; /* ROW count: iterates row count up for every row pulled from the spreadsheet */

echo '<div class="rowContainer">';
if (empty($values)) {
   print 'No data found.\n';
} else {
    
   echo '<div class="rowBreak rc'.$rc.'">';
   $rc++;
   foreach ($values as $row) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($row); $i++) {
          echo '<div class="item ic'.$ic.'" id="ic'.$ic.'">';
          echo $row[$i].'</div>';
          $ic++;
          
          if ($ic % 13 == 0) { 
          echo '</div><div class="rowBreak rc'.$rc.'">'; $rc++;}
         
       /* Needs an else if here that echos just a closing div instead of the close / open divs */
          
      }
    
                                        
      }
      }
echo '</div><!-- .rowContainerEnd -->';
```

I believe I need something like the following but I do not know what to compare $rc to in my original code.

```
else if ($rc == ??SOMETHING?? - 1) {
        echo '</div>';  
        $rc++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i could understand

```
else if ($i == sizeof($row) - 1) {
        echo '</div>';  
        $rc++;
    }
```

Should solve your problem